# C# - is there a way to stream a csv file into database?

Tags: c#, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, bulk-load

I saw lots of articles talking about using SqlBulkCopy to copy content from csv into database,
but they all need to load the data into a data table or data  set.

this is no good for me, since i deal with large amount of data, and i dont have powerful machine.

is there a way to stream data from the csv into database?

Thanks

Comment: You've tagged this C#, but is a strictly-SQL solution an option?  If you can get the data file to a location that is accessible from within your database, you can import it using a procedure or job.

Comment: That's not quite true, you can use OleDbReader (no need for datasets or datatables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article does show how to load the data directly to the database, without using a temp data table/ data set.

[C# - CSV Import Export](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx)

Just look for the moethod `SaveToDatabaseDirectly`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would probably be to read the CSV file line-by-line and execute an SQL `INSERT` command to add the data to the appropriate table in the database.