# Programmatically saving a SQL Server database to xml files and restoring it again

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to save a whole MS SQL 2008 Database into XML files... using asp.net.

Now I am bit lost here.. what would be the best method to achieve this? Datasets?

And I need to restore the database later again.. using these XML files. I am thinking about using datasets for reading the tables and writing to xml and using the SQLBulkCopy class to restore the database again. But I am not sure whether this would be the right approach..

Any clues and tips for me?

Comment: Tip: repost this question under "How do I avoid this situation?" I'm resisting the urge to downvote this since its a sincere and clear question.

Comment: I want to add a backup function to a custom CMS.. what would be the other option? I can't think of any.

Comment: IMO, storing a whole database in XML files is a bad idea. XML is big, and slow

Comment: Peter, SQL Server's backup system is amazing and supported by just about everything invented in the past 20 years. Why XML?

Comment: Doesn't have to be XML.. I could live with csv files or any other types of files for that matter. The solution just needs to be accessable by pure asp.net, so no SQL Server command line tools or anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

If you will need to restore it on the same server type (I mean SQL Server 2008 or higher) and don't care about ability to see actual data inside the XML do the following:

1. Programmatically backup the DB using "BACKUP DATABASE" T-SQL
2. Compress the backup
3. Convert the backup to Base64
4. Place the backup as the content of the XML file (like: <database name="..." compressionmethod="..." compressionlevel="...">the Base64 content here</database>
5. On the server where you need to restore it, download the XML, extract the Base64 content, use the attributes to know what compression was used. Decompress and restore using T-SQL "RESTORE" command.

Would that approach work?
For sure, if you need to see the content of the database, you would need to develop the XML scheme, go through each table etc. But, you won't have SPs/Views and other items backed up.

Comment: Interesting.. I will keep this in mind, but I need the ability to save only specific tables, too.

Comment: @David Lively - you're welcome ;) Usually there're some strange solutions :)

Comment: @Peter Siegmann - then you just answered your question above. If you need to store DATA, not the DATABASE - yes, use datasets and then serialize data into any format you need.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are talking about a CMS, I'm going to assume you are deploying into hosted environments where you might not have command line access.

Now, before I give you the link I want to state that this is a **BAD** idea.  XML is way too verbose to transfer large amounts of data.  Further, although it is relatively easy to pull data out, putting it back in will be difficult and a very time consuming development project in itself.

Next alert: as Denis suggested, you are going to miss all of your stored procedures, functions, etc.  Your best bet is to use the normal sql server backup / restore process. (Incidentally, I upvoted his answer).

Finally, the last time I dealt with XML and SQL Server we noticed interesting issues that cropped up when data exceeded a 64KB boundary.  Basically, at 63.5KB, the queries ran very quickly (200ms).  At 64KB, the query times jumped to over a minute and sometimes quite a bit longer.  We didn't bother testing anything over 100KB as that was taking 5 minutes on a fast/dedicated server with zero load.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx

See this for putting it back in:
[How to insert FOR AUTO XML result into table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749948/how-to-insert-for-auto-xml-result-into-table)

---

For kicks, here is a link talking about pulling the data out as json objects: http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2008/11/17/get-json-from-sql-server.aspx

you should also read (not for the faint of heart): http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Of course, the commentors all recommend building something using a CLR approach, but that's probably not available to you in a shared database hosting environment.

---

At the end of the day, if you are truly insistent on this madness, you might be better served by simply iterating through your table list and exporting all the data to standard CSV files.  Then, iterating the CSV files to load the data back in ala [C# - is there a way to stream a csv file into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348259/c-is-there-a-way-to-stream-a-csv-file-into-database)

---

Bear in mind that ALL of the above methods suffer from

1. long processing times due to the data overhead; which leads to
2. a high potential for failure due to the various time outs (page processing, command, connection, etc); and,
3. if your data model changes between the time it was exported and reimported then you're back to writing custom translation code and ultimately screwed anyway.

So, only do this if you really really have to and are at least somewhat of a masochist at heart.  If the purpose is simply to transfer some data from one installation to another, you might consider using one of the tools like [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) from [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com) to handle the transfer.

I don't care how much (or little) you make, the $1500 investment in their [developer bundle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-developer-bundle/) is much cheaper than the months of time you are going to spend doing this, fixing it, redoing it, fixing it again, etc. (for the record I do NOT work for them.  Their products are just top notch.)

Comment: Thank you for all the links and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate's SQL Packager lets you package a database into an exe or to a VS project, so you might want to take a look at that. You can specify which tables you want to consider for data.

Is there any specific reason you want to do this using xml?